# Variant on Poker with 3 card deck

Tags: poker-theory, poker-strategy

Imagine a 3 card deck consisting of J, Q, K. The two players are each dealt one card at random. Small blind is $1 and big blind is $2. What is the optimal strategy for small blind position and big blind position, dependent on the card, if each player is only allowed to raise at most once?

I'm interested in hearing what people's thoughts are on GTO. I've read about Kuhn poker and variants where each player posts ante, but the decision tree here seems much bigger and more complex.

Comment: How much are you allowed to raise?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that would be one of the most interesting games :D If BTN raises, then you know he has a King if he folds, you know he doesn't.

So if BTN raises, you just fold from blinds if he folds, you know what you have and what other player has, so there is no game here :)